# is it possible to repair a partially downloaded sqlite3 file

Tags: sqlite3

I was only able to partially download a SQLite3 database file, is it possible to repair the file so that it can be opened?

Unfortunately the device where the file came from is out of power and irretrievable.

If anybody can point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: There are some answers here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259692/how-to-recover-a-corrupt-sqlite3-database).